# Selecting dates from Pandas Panel without looping over items

Tags: python, pandas

I have panels full of stock data that are not aligned on trading days. You can use the code: dataFrame.ix[dateSet] to select dates from a pandas DataFrame but I want to do something similar with a panel and have resorted to looping over panels and rejoining them. So some kind of Panel.ix[daterange] would be useful.

```
def slicePanelOverTradingDates(panel = fpStockPanel, security = 'SPY'):
    # get the trading dates of the S&P starting with the first date of the panel's adjusted close item
    validSPXDates = DataReader('SPY','yahoo',panel['Adj Close'].index[0].date()).index
    # take the dates that are valid in the stock panel that intersect with the S&P's dates   and makes sure they're in order
    panelDatesOnSPXDays = list(set(panel['Adj Close'].index).intersection(set(validSPXDates)))
    panelDatesOnSPXDays.sort()
    # remakes the panel sliced only over the correct dates
    panelFrame = {}
    for x in panel.items:
        panelFrame[x] = panel[x].ix[panelDatesOnSPXDays]
    finalPanel = pd.Panel(panelFrame)
    return finalPanel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.loc` support multi-dimensional selections, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#selection-by-label); this applies to `.ix` and `.iloc` as well

```
In [18]: p = tm.makePanel()

In [19]: p
Out[19]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D

In [20]: p.loc[:,'2000-1-4':'2000-1-31']
Out[20]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 20 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-04 00:00:00 to 2000-01-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

Comment: Great - this works, thank you. Using the Syntax of the original question: tradingDates = DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', '2003-01-01')['Adj Close'].dropna().index  then d.loc[:, tradingDates]

Comment: you can select the other field as well, e.g. ``panel.loc[items,major_axis,minor_axis]``; if the item (or axis) is a label (rather than a list or idnexer), the dimensions of the result will be dropped, e.g. you will get a frame)